# Visual Studio 2017 Using Mocha

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, unit-testing, mocha.js, test-explorer

I have a nodejs project in Visual Studio 2017 and am trying to unit test using mocha.  For some reason Test Explorer can't find the unit tests if it requires any file not in node_modules.

I have a simple test index.spec.js and Test Explorer is able to find the unit tests:

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe('Index  Suite 1', function () {
    it('Test 1', function () {
        assert.ok(true, "This shouldn't fail");
    });

    it('Test 2', function () {
        assert.ok(1 === 1, "This shouldn't fail");
        assert.ok(false, "This should fail");
    });
});
```

I have an identical test heroes.spec.js with the addition of "var heroes = require('./heroes');" and it does not find the unit test.  I assume that it can't find heroes.  The file heroes.js resides in the same folder as heroes.spec.js.  I also tried it with ./heroes.js.  In both files, TestFramework is set to Mocha

This is the file heroes.spec.js

```
var assert = require('assert');

var heroes = require('./heroes');

describe('Heroes Test', function () {
    it('Test 1', function () {
        assert.ok(true, "This shouldn't fail");
    });

    it('Test 4', function () {
        assert.ok(1 === 1, "This shouldn't fail");
        assert.ok(false, "This should fail");
    });
});
```

I narrowed the problem.  heroes.js references other modules and one of the modules references db.js, which uses config to set dbConfig.  If I replace the code and hardcode the values, the unit tests are found.  I have a work around, but I would like to do it correctly.  I tried setting the environment variable, NODE_ENV=test, in the project properties and creating a test.config.  Still the problem exists.  Any idea of how to do this correctly?

Here is my work around
    //var dbConfig = config.get('dbConfig');

```
var dbConfig = {
    "user": "test",
    "password": "password",
    "server": "xxxx",
    "database": "Sandbox"
};
```

Thanks

Comment: if ./heroes is not found than an error will be thrown and execution will stop this doesn't seem to be your case. I believe mocha is unable to find your heroes.spec.js file because maybe it's in a subdirectory of test directory

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a solution using Visual Studio 2017, so I downloaded/installed visual studio code.  Using Visual Studio Code, I was able to debug my unit test and find the problem.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  I could not get it to work using Visual Studio 2017.  I was able to get it to work using Visual Studio Code.  This is the free version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I meant 'Visual Studio Code'. It works in 'Visual Studio 2017 just fine, but I couldn't make it work in 'VSCode'.